# AngularJS dynamic styling with extended class

Tags: css, angularjs, ng-class, ng-style

I am trying to display a status label that will contain different background colors and text depending on the status in AngularJs (e.g. 'New' = green, 'Active' = yellow).  I currently have a css file with

```
.status {
    padding: 4px 8px;
    font-size: 12px;
    line-height: 12px;
    color: white;
    border-radius: 16px;
}

.status.new {
    background-color: #673AB7;
    border: 1pt solid #673AB7;
}

.status.active {
    background-color: #4CAF50;
    border: 1pt solid #4CAF50;
}
```

In my html I am referencing multiple classes like below

```
<span class="status pull-right">{{statusProperty}}</span>
```

Is it possible to combine class with ng-class to use extended classes or can this be accomplished through ng-style?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use `ng-class` along with `class`

In your case it would go like this:

```
<span class="status pull-right" ng-class="{'new': <condition_for_being_green>, 'active': <condition_for_being_yelow>}">{{statusProperty}}</span>
```

This will make your element to have the classes `status` and `pull-right` through the `class` attribute and to have the `new | active` classes when the conditions for being green and yellow are met respectively.

It means the element will have the classes

- `status pull-right new` if the `<condition_for_being_green>` is true
- `status pull-right active` if the `<condition_for_being_yellow>` is true
- `status pull-right new active` if the `<condition_for_being_green>` and `<condition_for_being_yellow>` are true
- `status pull-right` if the `<condition_for_being_green>` and `<condition_for_being_yellow>` are false

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can apply both `class` and `ng-class` to the same element, as states [the reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClass). The only caution is to avoid interpolated expressions in the `class` attribute when also `ng-class` is present.

Also, of course it is better using a CSS class instead of an inline style, considering both reusability and the fact that you already have written the needed classes.